# SSL error: The date of the certificate is invalid , React Native WebView

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, mobile, expo

so im using expo to develop an android application , i want to display a web page on the screen using WebView and I keep getting this error :

```
Encountered an error loading page, Object {
  "canGoBack": false,
  "canGoForward": false,
  "code": 4,
  "description": "SSL error: The date of the certificate is invalid",
  "loading": false,
  "target": 1927,
  "title": "",
  "url": "https://www.google.com/",
}
```

my dependencies :

```
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"expo": "~44.0.0",
"react-native-web": "0.17.1",
"react-native-webview": "11.15.0",
```

how im using the WebView :

```
<WebView 
  style={styles.pdf}
  source={{ uri : 'https://www.google.com' }}
/>
```

I should mention that the WebView works just fine on the Emulator however , when I test the app on a real device i get the ssl error.

Comment: I had the same issue, but on the Emulator instead.  Turns out the date of the emulator is wrong.  Fixing the date resolves the error.